# SQL Reporting Services in SharePoint Mode Prompts for Login

Tags: 2010, authentication, reporting-services, reports

**Scenario**: We currently have SQL Reporting Services 2008 R2 in a scale-out deployment on two servers.  SSRS is configured in SharePoint integrated mode with our SharePoint 2010 servers (configured with NTLM authentication).  We have numerous reports that work without issue.

**Problem**:  On 3 of our reports, while running the report it prompts the user to login (even though they are already authenticated).  Under any user accounts it prompts the user to login and fails to do so.  The same reports work just fine when deployed to SSRS in Native Mode rather than SharePoint Mode.

Other reports use the same data connection without issue.  And the users have contribute access to the folders that house the data connection, shared datasets, and the reports.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a support ticket with Microsoft, we found the issue.  The issue only occurred when running the report through the load balancer.  If we accessed a front-end directly, it ran just fine.  Our F5 load balancer had a 5 minute timeout set on connections.  So, when the report ran and took longer than 5 minutes, the connection was lost and caused the errors.

By setting the timeout on the connections through the F5 load balancer to allow enough time for the report to finish (10 minutes), everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint integrated mode, the report server uses authentication and permissions settings defined in the SharePoint Web application to control access to reports. You need to ensure the users have enough permissions. Please check out below article how to do that:

[How to: Set Permissions for Report Server Items on a SharePoint Site (Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283150.aspx)

For more details on assigning permissions check out the article : [Granting Permissions on Report Server Items on a SharePoint Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326215.aspx)

Comment: This is not an obvious permissions issue as I login as a user who is both a SharePoint administrator (site collection admin) and a SQL administrator of the SQL database it is accessing.  The report starts to run and then prompts for a login.

Comment: From your question, it seems reports works for Farm administrator and not for other users.Right?

Comment: Updated the question, I had misspoken about that, it works that way under native mode, but not SharePoint mode.

Comment: Any other ideas?